# Webstorm invalid code inspections on html script tag

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

I'm working in Webstorm 8.0.4 and whenever i put a script tag in my HTML document like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

I'm getting this error on the `src` part of that line:

> This selector does'nt have any properties and will not be rendered

This is the first time i'm seeing this error, i'm working with this IDE longer then just today and never saw that error before. Is it a update of the IDE?

Whenever i'm between the two quotation marks with my cursor in the `src` attribute and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> for the code hints, i get a list of HTML element names.

**Questions**

- How does this come?
- How can i solve this?

Comment: I know it may sounds unsatisfying, but did you already asked the jetbrains support or posted a bug report? Not wanting to create a YouTrack account doesn't count. ;-)

Comment: Screenshot please, preferably whole file (create such small file that would reproduce the issue) using Darcula or Default color scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How does this come**

Seems that some language (CSS?) is injected into the `src` attribute value for some reason. Do you have any custom language injections configured?

If this is a predefined injection configured in Settings/Language injections, just remove/disable it.

**How can i solve this?**

If this is a 'local' injection created via `Inject language/reference` intention, then it can be removed with `Alt+Enter, Un-inject language`.

See [this link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-language-injections.html#d644612e226) for more information

Comment: Yes i did, it's fixed now. Do you still want me to put up screenshots of the injected language refference? Maybe you can explain then how to remove it for other people?

Comment: I don't need screenshots as the problem is fixed for you

Comment: Alright, but what if other people experience the same problem? Should'nt we put up some more information?

Comment: what information? I think, other users will need to search web for solution or contact support

Comment: information how to further solve this problems, in my opinion i thought this Question was for that. You're just giving an example what the problem "might" be. In this case you were right but i had to find out how to remove the language. So i'll find this answer usefull, but other people having the same issue maybe not :)

Comment: it was just the most probable reason for your problem. And my suggestion helped you. In any case, such problems don't have a single evident reason, so no universal solution can be offered. Other users can also try it and, if my answer is not helpful, ask more questions, providing more information, etc.

Comment: Ofcourse, but still. Now people still dont know how to solve it, what is also in my 'question'. I also asked "How can i solve this".

Comment: if the issue is caused by language injection - then the obvious solution is to disable this injection... If this is a predefined injection configured in Settings/Language injections, just remove/disable it. If this is a 'local' ionjection created via 'inject language' intention, then it can be removed with Alt+Enter, Un-inject language. See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-language-injections.html#d644612e226. Is it the information you were looking for?

Comment: Well, there you go. Can you edit that in your answer then so i can accept it?